# How do I replace nth character in a String with a new character?

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I have been asked to write a class that encodes a given sentence using specific rules. This class should use loops and `Stringbuffer`. The rules are:

- Each dot '.' is to be replaced by '*'.
- Every 3rd character (if this character is not a space or a dot)
  should be eliminated.
- Add at the end of the new sentence a number representing total number
  of eliminated characters.

I have written the code, but I am not able to understand why it is not working. Can anyone help?

For example:

> sentence = "Katie likes to observe nature."

It should be transformed to:

> "Kaie iks t obere ntue*8"

However, using my code I get:
"Katie likes to observe nature*."

Thank you!

```
public void createEncodedSentence() {

    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    int counter = 0;
    char a;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        a = sentence.charAt(i);

        if (a == '.') {
            buff.append('*');
        }
        if (a != ' ' && a != '.') {
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter % 3 == 0) {
            buff.append("");
        }
        buff.append(sentence.charAt(i));


    }

    encodedSentence = buff.toString();

}
```

Comment: Besides, " it is not working" is a useless description. Please describe the problem in detail.

Comment: The output for `Katie likes to observe nature.` should be `Kaie lies to obere atre*6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue with your logic is that after you append a *String* to `buff` you continue with *that* iteration instead of jumping to the next character in the String.

Change your method to as follows :

```
public static StringBuffer createEncodedSentence(String sentence) {

    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
    int counter = 0;
    char a;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        a = sentence.charAt(i);
        if (a == '.') {
            buff.append("*");
            continue;
        }
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0 && a != ' ' && a != '.') {
            counter++;
            continue;
        }
        buff.append(sentence.charAt(i));
    }
    buff.append(counter);
    return buff;

}
```

Logic:

- If the *character* is a `.` then we append a `*` and jump to the next character in the sentence.
- If it is the 3rd index then we increment the counter and jump to the next character.
- At the end of the for-loop iteration, we add the number of
  *characters* that have been replaced

Comment: Thanks that help a lot. But why at the end we 'return buff'? Can I convert that to String and store in newSentence? encodedSentence = buff.toString();
  return encodedSentence;

Comment: Yes. You can just call `.toString()` on `buff`. But if you do that you need to change the return type of the method to `String`.

Comment: // if I add this code the I get an error
     buff.append(counter);
     encodedSentence = buff.toString();
  return encodedSentence;
// error: non-static variable encodedSentence cannot be referenced from a static

Comment: I have declared it in the class but outside the method as private String encodedSentence;

Comment: That's because you are accessing a non-static field from a static method. Declare it using `private static String encodedSentence;`